# "Push chord". What's that?

Tags: theory, harmony, terminology, latin-jazz

I came across [this post](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/90672/45266.) the other day that referenced a "push chord". What does "push chord" mean in that context? Is that a term specific to Bossa Nova (a latin jazz genre), or is it just a term I haven't heard before?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not the chord so much as the rhythm that gets pushed. Nothing much to do with bossa, but it happens all the time in a lot of pieces,

The emphasis is expected to come on the 1st beat of the next bar, but instead, comes a little earlier, usually on the & of 4 of the bar before (in 4/4).

It effectively puts the emphasis where the next heavy beat comes a little earlier than anticipated - `a quaver before we expect it. instead of actually *on* the beat of the next bar, it's on the quaver before. Been around for at least 60 years and so is nothing new!

Answer (score 3):

I was wondering too, when I read this term in the other question about the Bossa Nova.

Then I've found this link (s.below) that confirms what Tim explains.

It says: Rhythm is also defined by chords and ***where*** they fall, a little **earlier** or **later** - I would say similar or the same as *off-beat*:

I thought, the push chord must be what I know from the big band sound in the final chord (or final 2 chords) of a big band piece, off-beat or - in German we would say "vorgezogen" that means actually the opposite of push: PULL!): the final chord, the POLY-Chord, which is often "vorgezogen" (pushed down, or later.

Well, here is the link. It explains it perfect and better than I could:

https://www.musicradar.com/tuition/tech/how-to-add-interest-using-pushed-chords-640295

a good example must be **SMOKE ON THE WATER**

[image]